# Docker command with build / run / etc. "too many open files"

Tags: docker, build, command

Im installed Docker on server machine (with Ubuntu 16.04), but trying run any commands, I get this error:

> "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: too many open files"

Please, who know how solve this issue?

Docker Info:

```
Containers: 18
Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 18
Images: 4
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 76
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-ini
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-59-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.953 GiB
Name: web.renderdeal.com
ID: LXNZ:I6HH:ZVBB:KS3V:3WCT:ADWY:C2MZ:QJ37:VZUU:EZ6T:PYWO:66WQ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: animarender
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

> /Docker Info
>
> docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   60ccb22
 Built:        Thu Feb 23 11:02:43 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64


Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   60ccb22
 Built:        Thu Feb 23 11:02:43 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

> / docker version

Comment: P.S. but simple "hello-world" from docker hub run correcly

Answer (score -1):

Considering Docker status seems OK, check if the issue is on your side (as in [this ticket](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/issues/1111#issuecomment-278303170))

> Let's check on the current open files

```
lsof | grep "rclone" | wc -l
returns 6458
```

> Now, Check on current ulimit

```
ulimit -n
returns 1024
```

> Set that to 9000 and Check again

```
ulimit -n 9000 && ulimit -n
returns 9000
```

> To make the `ulimit` more persistent you can either edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`
>   and add :

```
* soft nofile 9000 + reboot
```

> or write it into your user's `.bashrc`

Comment: Didn't work for me even I change ulimit -n 9000

Comment: @AliYeşilkanat almost 5 years later, I wouldn't know for sure what other factor would matter here. Your current version of OS and Docker might be quite different as the one from 2017.